# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un script que me permita monitorear un sistema de archivos y directorios?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola estoy iniciando a programar en python, mi programa o script realiza auditar archivos y directorios que sean modificados, pero lo quiero hacer para los sistemas operativos windows y linux.

quiero saber si esta bien o que le falta, ojo lo quiero hacer con bibliotecas propias de python, no con repositorios, el script es el siguiente

```
import os         # Libreria para poder conocer el path del directorio
import time       # Delay
import sys        # Libreria para salidas y parametros

# =====================
# Definiendo funciones
# =====================
def directorio_info():
    # os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))  Imprime el directorio actual donde se encuentre úbicado el script
    try:
        from os import startfile
    except ImportError:
        from webbrowser import open as startfile
    carpeta = 'C:/Users/Juan Ordaz/Documents/Bitacoras'
    ruta_app = os.getcwd()
    total = 0
    contenido = os.scandir(carpeta)
    linea = '='*25, 'Inicio Registro', '='*25
    linea2 = '='*50
    fichero = 0
    files = fichero
    for carpeta, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/Users/Juan Ordaz/Documents/Bitacoras'):
        print(linea)
        print('\nRuta del Directorio:', carpeta)
        for elemento in files:
            fichero += 1
            files = carpeta + os.sep + elemento
            estado = os.stat(files)
            tamaño = estado.st_size
            ult_acceso = time.ctime(estado.st_atime)
            modificado = time.ctime(estado.st_mtime)
            total += tamaño
            print(linea2)
            print('Nombre del fichero es:', elemento)
            print('Última Modificación del fichero:', modificado)
            print('Último acceso del fichero es:', ult_acceso)
            print('Tamaño del fichero en (Kb):', round(tamaño/1024, 1))
    print(linea2)
    print('Núm. ficheros:', fichero)

directorio_info()
```

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: ¿cual es pronblema?, lo que le falta dependera de los funcionalidades que planteo al iniciar su proyecto

Comment: Lo que busco que me indique cuando un fichero sea borrado y no encuentro un método que se pueda usar para que me indique eso, cuando fue que fue borrado un archivo y un directorio